# Loading 2 google maps using the same initialize function

Tags: google-maps

I want to load 2 google maps using 1 initialize functions on the same page using division class. But the maps are not getting loaded. Can anyone help?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp">
        </script>
        <script>
 function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}
</script>
<body>

<div class="map-canvas" style="height:200px;width:200px;border: 1px solid black;" >
<script>
initialize();       
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
</script>
</div><!-- /.panel-body -->

<div class="map-canvas" style="height:200px;width:200px;border: 1px solid black;" >
<script>
initialize();       
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
</script>
</div><!-- /.panel-body -->


                                        </body>
                                        </html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok there are some mayor problems in you source:

1. Invalid HTML structure

Your script has to be placed in the `head` tag above the `body` tag like:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp">
    </script>

    <script>
        var map;
        var map2;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);
            map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'),
                mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>    
</head>
```

2. You can't initialize the google map by a container class name. All containers had to be      unique. As you can see i am creating 2 individual maps 'map`and`map2` and therefore i need two seperate containers in the body tag like:

   ```
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
   <div id="map-canvas2"></div>
   ```
3. You don't have to call the initialize function in your body tag because it will be called throught the eventListener on window - load

   ```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   ```

So lets bring it all together:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bcdLnLjw/)

Answer (score 1):

1. getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements
2. you need to run the initialize function once the document onload event has fired.

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  elems = document.getElementsByClassName('map-canvas');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(elems[i],
      mapOptions);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div class="map-canvas" style="height:200px;width:200px;border: 1px solid black;">
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body -->

<div class="map-canvas" style="height:200px;width:200px;border: 1px solid black;">
  <script>
    initialize();
     //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
  </script>
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body -->
```